# FFMPEG stream won't show up on Justin.tv

Tags: shell-script, ffmpeg

```sh
INRES="1366x768"                                            # input resolution
OUTRES="1366x768"                                           # Output resolution
FPS="35"                                                    # target FPS
QUAL="medium"                                               # one of the many FFMPEG preset on (k)ubuntu found in `/usr/share/ffmpeg`
                                                            # If you have low bandwidth, put the qual preset on 'fast' (upload bandwidth)
                                                            # If you have medium bandwitch put it on normal to medium
STREAM_KEY="Obviously I won't post my live key"   # This is your streamkey generated by jtv/twitch found at: http://www.justin.tv/broadcast/adv_other

ffmpeg -f x11grab -s "$INRES" -r "$FPS" -i :0.0+0,0 -itsoffset 00:00:01 \
       -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0,0  -vcodec libx264 -preset "$QUAL" -s "$OUTRES" \
       -acodec libmp3lame -ab 96k -threads 6 -qscale 5 -b:v 1024k -ar 44100 \
       -f flv "rtmp://live.justin.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
```

This is what I have been using, but the stream won't screencast.  Any help?